# Calling command asks for interaction even if I have set it to false

Tags: symfony, symfony5, symfony-console

Using Symfony 5.4, I have created a command to run several commands (just to refresh my app quickly), here is my code:

```
    // @see https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html
    $commands = [
        'doctrine:schema:drop' => [
            '--force' => true,
        ],
        'doctrine:schema:update' => [
            '--force' => true,
        ],
        'doctrine:fixtures:load' => [
            '-n' => true,
            '--group' => ['dev'],
        ],
        'fos:elastica:populate' => []
    ];

    foreach ($commands as $command => $arguments) {
        $output->writeln([
            'Execute command',
            $command,
            '========================',
            '',
        ]);

        $command = $this->getApplication()->find($command);
        $command->run(new ArrayInput($arguments), $output);
    }
```

It's working fine, except the command `doctrine:fixtures:load` is asking for:

> Careful, database "store" will be purged. Do you want to continue? (yes/no)

I have to set `y` to continue.

Looking at the help of the command, it seems `-n` (or `--no-interaction`) is what I want, and indeed, launching:

```
bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --group=dev -n
```

manualy works fine.

Why the `$arguments` are not working for this command ? Did I miss something ?

Comment: It's a old way to execute command in sequence you can use `Make` file please check this https://www.strangebuzz.com/en/snippets/the-perfect-makefile-for-symfony

Comment: I agree about CI/CD, my aim was to have a simple command to run without reinstalling the project each time I need to update my fixtures / population in Elastic. We use it, doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$nonInteractiveArguments = new ArrayInput($arguments);
$nonInteractiveArguments->setInteractive(false);
$command->run($nonInteractiveArguments, $output);
```

to set Input interactivity to false.